# Why do the vector values not get move to the Ordering function in the below code?

Tags: rust

I am a Rust noob and I have been going through a few videos and articles. I was following this article [here](https://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html/#:%7E:text=The%20.into_iter%20%28%29%20function%20creates%20a%20IntoIter%3CT%3E%20type,the%20words%20owned%20or%20consumed%20interchangeably%20with%20moved.) about Rust iterators.

When it is explaining `iter_mut()` it uses the following example.

```
fn main() {
    let mut teams = [
        [ ("Jack", 20), ("Jane", 23), ("Jill", 18), ("John", 19), ],
        [ ("Bill", 17), ("Brenda", 16), ("Brad", 18), ("Barbara", 17), ]
    ];

    let teams_in_score_order = teams
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|team| {
            team.sort_by(|&a, &b| a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse());
            team
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
    println!("Teams: {:?}", teams_in_score_order);
}
```

Here `team.sort_by(|&a, &b| a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse())` VS Code tells me that these are the variable types.

```
   a: (&str, i32)
   b: (&str, i32)
```

So here in the closure `a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse()`, `a` is not a borrowed value (according to my current understanding). So why wouldn't it get dropped at the end of the closure? I am assuming, that if `a` gets dropped, then there would not be any items left in the vector at the end of this function. One more question: Once a value is passed as a borrowed value, what does it mean to access without the `&`?

Also, I was trying to understand, defining closure parameters using `&`. I understand `&` means to reference/borrow a value. However here, I removed `&` from `|&a, &b|` and it still worked, but at that point, types were defined as
`a: &(&str, i32)`
`b: &(&str, i32)`. Here what does it mean by having or not having `&` in the parameter definition in `|&a, &b|`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure to not miss the difference between `|&a, &b|` and `|a: &_, b: &_|`. It's similar to the difference between `|(a, b)|` and `|x: (_, _)|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not get moved because `(&str, i32)` implements Copy (as both `&str` and `i32` both implement Copy), so instead of moving it just copies the tuple.

You can test this by trying to compile this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut teams = [
        [ ("Jack".to_owned(), 20), ("Jane".to_owned(), 23), ("Jill".to_owned(), 18), ("John".to_owned(), 19), ],
        [ ("Bill".to_owned(), 17), ("Brenda".to_owned(), 16), ("Brad".to_owned(), 18), ("Barbara".to_owned(), 17), ]
    ];

    let teams_in_score_order = teams
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|team| {
            team.sort_by(|&a, &b| a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse());
            team
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
    println!("Teams: {:?}", teams_in_score_order);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15aa02575f5833ee39e29398ee0d9e82)

The compiler will now complain that it is being moved, since the type is now `(String, i32)`, and `String` does not implement Copy.

> Also, I was trying to understand, defining closure parameters using &.

I believe using & when defining arguments in a closure is just sugar for the de-referencing each variable. E.g.

```
|&a, &b| a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse()
```

is the same as

```
|a, b| { 
    let a = *a;
    let b = *b;
    
    a.1.cmp(&b.1).reverse()
}
```

Though I am not 100% sure this is correct.

Comment: "using & when defining arguments in a closure is just sugar for the de-referencing" - it's not a sugar, it's pattern matching. However, in this case the pattern matching is equivalent to dereferencing, that's correct.

Comment: @Cerberus, does function parameter pattern matching differ from general pattern matching using ```match```? Can you please point me to some docs that I can read about function parameter pattern matching? I could not find any materials except for the general ```match```.  Thank you!

Comment: It's all the same, save for the fact that the patterns in function arguments (as well as in `let` bindings) must be irrefutable, i.e. infallible (you can't match on enum variant there, for example). Here's the reference on patterns in general: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html, and here's the corresponding part of the Book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html.